# nginx spam 404 errors

Tags: nginx, security, spam, http-status-code-404

My server is spammed by multiples XXX domains, there is a lot of 404 errors in my logs and i can't find the solution to stop that.

```
2015/07/31 09:13:20 [error] 7070#0: *610 open() "/var/www/domain/mobile/www/www-sexvideo-shifuni.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 162.158.252.53, server: m.domain.com, request: "GET /www-sexvideo-shifuni.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.sextoysnmore.com"
```

As u can see i have theses errors logs each seconds..

I tried to put a file with bad referers :

```
map $http_referer $bad_referer {
hostnames;

default                           0;

# Put regexes for undesired referers here
"~sextoysnmore.org"             1;

}
```

and

```
if ($bad_referer) {
    return 444;
}
```

but there is always spam from this domain.. or others..

Anyone have a solution ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: You could put the regex for domains in the server name and then not log those or log them to a different file

Answer (score 1):

You should list all the domains you really don't care about in one "special" server stanza, and disable all logs for those domains:

```
server {
  server_name www.sextoysnmore.org;

  access_log off;
  error_log /dev/null;
}
```

Comment: interesting solution)